# How to give the h:selectManyCheckbox a fixed name attribute?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` and they have in the HTML source an autogenerated `name` attribute. I need to give it a fixed `name` attribute. How can I do that?

Here's what I am using for now:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{tab.values}" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItems value="#{tab.checkBoxes}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Comment: They by default **already** have the same name (it would otherwise have been a huge bug in JSF). Aren't you actually asking how to give it a fixed name instead of an autogenerated one?

Comment: @BalusC, yes i was asking about fixed name for all checkboxes as in the answer.

Comment: You should then ask that as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `id` attribute:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox id="someName" value="#{tab.values}" layout="pageDirection">
```

Also look here :

[JSF HTML Tag Referenceh:selectManyCheckbox](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectManyCheckbox.html)